# How to chronological write values in column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop, chronological

Im new to Python so please excuse me if my code and logic isn't the best. Gotta start somewhere :)

im having trouble chronological writing values in a new column of a dataframe.

If the current and next value of _cycletime stay the same the counter stays as is it.
If the current and next value of _cycletime are not the same the counter is increased by one.

Afterwards I'm trying to write the values of p in a new column named _cyclenumber.

```
p=1
for i in range((len(df81))-2):
     if   (df81['_cycletime'].iloc[i] == df81['_cycletime'].iloc[i+1]):
          p=p 
     elif (df81['_cycletime'].iloc[i] != df81['_cycletime'].iloc[i+1]):
          p+=1 
df81['_cyclenumber'] =  p
```

exemplary excerpt from df81:

| Index | _time | _power | _cycletime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-30T11:00:28.042Z | 12 | 55.4379997253 |
| 2 | 2022-07-30T11:00:28.554Z | 10 | 55.4379997253 |
| 3 | 2022-07-30T11:00:29.068Z | 11.5 | 55.4119987488 |
| 4 | 2022-07-30T11:00:29.623Z | 8 | 55.4119987488 |

But instead of a chronological list I only get the same value in every cell:

[Output I get vs Output I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICDB7.png)

The number 64 comes from the amount of different cycletimes in the timeframe which is correct.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: please add your `df81` as a table or dict using `to_dict` method

Comment: I've added an examplary excerpt of df81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uniques = df['_cycletime'].unique().tolist()
df['_cyclenumber'] = df['_cycletime'].map(lambda x: uniques.index(x) + 1)
```

your manner (corrected, don't recommended):

```
p = 1
df.loc[0, "_cyclenumber"] = p
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df['_cycletime'].iloc[i] != df['_cycletime'].iloc[i-1]:
        p+=1 
    df.loc[i, "_cyclenumber"] = p
```